# Is there an intersphinx mapping to wxpython?

Tags: wxpython, python-sphinx

I would like to add intersphinx mappings to the documentation of my project. It worked fine with python, but I can't find a mapping to wxpython. Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an item

```
'wxpython': ('https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/', None)
```

to the intersphinx_mapping entry in conf.py solves the problem. :-)